# Randomizing a variable with other variables inside

Tags: php

I have this code, it generates a list of numbers with range, it have a variable inside, and I need to get randomly 1 of the output numbers

```
$lprincipiopregunta = implode(',' , range('1', $clpyrdesde, '2'));
```

If $clpyrdesde was 18 the output will be "1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17" but I need to get randomly 1 of the output numbers.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Hint: Use [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) before imploding.

Answer (score 0):

If [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) is so important to you and you must have it in your code,

You can use explode after it, and [rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) function with it like this

```
$lprincipiopregunta = implode(',' , range('1', $clpyrdesde, '2'));
$explodeit = explode(",", $lprincipiopregunta);
echo $explodeit[rand(0,count($explodeit)-1)];
```

Or [array_rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) with [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

```
$lprincipiopregunta = implode(',' , range('1', $clpyrdesde, '2'));
$explodeit = explode(",", $lprincipiopregunta);
echo $explodeit[array_rand($explodeit)];
```

Or as I recommended to use [array_rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) before [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php), like this.

```
$array = range('1', $clpyrdesde, '2');
echo $array[array_rand($array)];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a random number from that, you don't need implode().

Just do this:

```
$numbers = range(1, $clpyrdesde, 2);
$lprincipiopregunta = $numbers[array_rand($numbers)];
```

Comment: Hi Eneas, array_rand in this case take key of element not the value, the right code is `$lprincipiopregunta = $numbers[array_rand($numbers)];`, it gives random key to the array to print the value. i hope my reply helps you :)

Comment: @MohammedAlhanafi, you're right. Updated the answer.

Comment: I'm very happy to help you :).